# How to remove entries from PATH variable using command prompt Win 7?

Tags: java, windows, maven, cmd

I am unable to update/add System variables through control panel as there is Restriction set on my desktop. 
I wanted to update path variable to add java and maven executable directories. I used setx to do this but it resulted in PATH variable to be set as {earlier PATH value};{M2_HOME value\bin};{JAVA_HOME value\bin};{earlier PATH value}

```
setx PATH "%M2_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
```

Not sure what is wrong in above command, so now I wanted to make things as they were earlier. I want to set PATH variable to its earlier value. I tried below command but it didn't work:

```
setx PATH "{earlier PATH value}"
```

Comment: Two things of note here: First, you should probably leave most of the PATH intact instead of blindly setting your value. Second, using setx that way can easily lead to the variable value becoming too long because all environment variables are expanded. This causes more or less random programs to not be accessible anymore.

Comment: Setx adds to the path. So `setx path c:\myfolder` will ADD MyFolder to the path. So it's different to `set` or `path` which work on the current environment for that CMD. `Setx` works on the underlying stores (HKCU\HKLM\Autoexec.bat). Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` in Regedit and delete `path` and start again.

Comment: @Noodles thanks for pointing out the mistake. You have suggested to delete path from registry but I have many restrictions on my computer. It seems I cannot access regedit as Run is also not accessible by me. Is there any other way without using regedit to set PATH value absolutely and not relatively to existing value?

Comment: You can always double click regedit in C:\windows\system32. Try `reg delete hkcu\environment /v path /f`.

Comment: @Noodles Thanks a lot!! :-)

Comment: @Noodles: that's not quite true.  `setx` without the `/m` option sets the user's path, which is appended to the system path.  If you run `setx` twice with different paths, only the last one will be kept.